# How are you able to access the Kubeflow dashboard?

Tags: minikube, kubeflow

I am new to kubeflow and I am trying to access the dashboard, but no success. I am running kubernetes locally installed via minikube. My lasta attempt was running the following command:

```
kubectl create -f https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/master/components/centraldashboard/config/centraldashboard-config.yaml -n kubeflow
```

But it gives the following error:
"kubectl create -f https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/centraldashboard/config/centraldashboard-config.yaml -n kubeflow
error: error parsing https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/centraldashboard/config/centraldashboard-config.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 206: mapping values are not allowed in this context
"

Any help will be much appreciated.

Tried many other things according to gemini

Comment: Might be useful to include the code that is on the offending line of 206.

Comment: there is no line 206 in the yaml file, that's the thing.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know if this is the correct way to access the dashboard :(

Comment: I think the error line is in the code you are using from the github.

Comment: But keep in mind its probably not an error in the original code .. its that we need to see that line to see what it is expecting so we can compare to the yml and find the offending character or issue.

Comment: I see! I will try to find it.